# Error: Schema changed for Timestamp field

Tags: google-bigquery

Suddenly some of our queries started to fail with a weird error.

```
Error: Schema changed for Timestamp field timestamp
Job ID: aerobic-forge-504:job_TX7MOFd-OPDgKGkE7vdamX8Et4E

Job ID: aerobic-forge-504:job_j7SbCVXdzcH9ZhOi2QyYODi58H4
```

As I know BQ engineers are checking these, hopefully this will be picked up.

Comment: I am on it - will get back to you when I have more info.

Comment: I will be getting in touch with you outside of StackOverflow thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is a result of internal timestamp handling changes applied tonight, and if you are getting this crash, you must contact Google support in order to fix the issue.

They are also working to better handle the timestamps in future.